# Why would a native messaging host for a chrome extension with a UI hang?

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome-extension, keychain

I have a native messaging host for a chrome extension that reads from the keychain in OS X (using [Apple's keychain service](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html)). I make the call to `chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage` when the [browser action page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) is opened. When the keychain is already unlocked, the native program runs fine and returns a response on standard out. The problem occurs when the keychain is locked so OS X prompts the user to unlock the keychain with a UI alert (similar to [this](http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9v6v7vUpd1qm7unw.png)). The problem is that the native program hangs when it is called and the prompt doesn't appear immediately. The prompt only appears once I close the browser action popup, and it only appears briefly (less than a second). I know that the native application is running while waiting for the UI prompt since I added logs for when it starts and exits (I also check `ps`).

Does anyone know why the native application might be hanging? I thought that maybe the UI window was causing things to be blocked, so I tried forking a new thread in the native application to open the keychain. Unfortunately, that didn't work either.

When I run the program directly from the command line, I don't run into any of these issues and the prompt to unlock the keychain appears immediately.

Ps. I've tried `chrome.runtime.connectNative` too and that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the function I was using to read from standard in was waiting for an EOF so under certain circumstances, the native application was just suspended indefinitely.